# C# How to calculate X Y Z coordinates to move a group of objects?

Tags: c#, 3d, coordinates

I'm working on a map generator for a popular 3D game engine just to see if I can. I've created a simple set of tiles to test with, such as corner pieces and vert/horizontal hallways. All tiles are the same size (192 l x 192 w x 136 h), and consist of planes to represent walls, floor, and ceiling. I've coded the logic for generating the tile order and am now ready to set the coordinates.

For example sake, I'm trying to move a tile up (Y-axis) exactly 192 units.

Before I made these tiles, I was testing with single objects and simply added 192 units to the object's Y-axis. That worked fine. However, after testing a move up with one of these tiles, I notice it's more than the Y-axis that needs calculating.

Here's what the tile map file looks like before the position is moved upwards 192 units:

https://pastebin.com/6iqQwN50

```
solid
{
    "id" "2"
    side
    {
        "id" "1"
        "plane" "(0 192 8) (192 192 8) (192 0 8)"
        "material" "CONCRETE/BAGGAGE_CONCRETEFLOORA"
        "uaxis" "[1 0 0 0] 0.25"
        "vaxis" "[0 -1 0 0] 0.25"
        "rotation" "0"
        "lightmapscale" "16"
        "smoothing_groups" "0"
    }
```

And here's what it looks like after the move:

https://pastebin.com/7cCnTndZ

```
solid
{
    "id" "2"
    side
    {
        "id" "1"
        "plane" "(0 192 8) (0 384 8) (192 384 8)"
        "material" "CONCRETE/BAGGAGE_CONCRETEFLOORA"
        "uaxis" "[1 0 0 0] 0.25"
        "vaxis" "[0 -1 0 256] 0.25"
        "rotation" "0"
        "lightmapscale" "16"
        "smoothing_groups" "0"
    }
```

I might be in over my head, but is there a C# class or perhaps function to help me position the X Y Z coordinates of these objects?

If it helps, I'm referring to this site as documentation on the code structure for planes:

https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Valve_Map_Format#Planes

I have an idea how to accomplish this, such as comparing the before and after code above and calculating the changed axis for every plane, but there must be a better way to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard class/method in C# that will do this for you.

It is also important to understand that there is an infinite number of possible combinations of points that will define the same plane. According to the documentation that you referred to these are simply three points in the plane (which are not on one line).

This means that adding a fixed amount to all Y coordinates will move the plane in the Y direction.